# Regex for validation of string with '+' operator

Tags: objective-c, regex, string

I have some strings given below:

```
 + sfsf +
 + sfsfsf + sfsfs
 + sfsfsf + sfsfs +
 sfsfsf +
 sfsfsf + sfsfsf
 sfsfsf s+ sfs fs+ sf
 sfsf+sfs+sf
 sfsfs+ sfsf +
 sfsfsfs+
 +sfsfsf
```

I need a regex to validated these strings.

If i give the string as "sfsfs + sass + jsjfns", the regex must output as valid  otherwise invalid.

The string will contain "word + word" and the regex should accept it. I need the regex in objective-c.

Comment: It's probably easier without regex. Just split the string on all + signs. Then check that each of the substrings contains a word or not (possibly this part is easiest with regex).

Comment: Will try and let u know. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: so `/^sfsfs \+ sass \+ jsjfns$/`?

Comment: @dev-null I'm pretty sure this is wrong. I think Op is not asking for the literal example given but wants something to validate that the string is balanced. `/^(\w+ ?\+ ?)*\w+$/`

Comment: @iismathwizard...Thanks for the regex. it works like magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
^(\w+ ?\+ ?)*\w+$
```

It looks like you want to make sure that the operators have the correct number of operands.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aL0jJ2/1)